# Javascript: <script src=jquery...only if condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, conditional-statements

I'm developing in javascript and would like to insert a script only if a condition is verified.

For example:

```
var a = exampleVariable;

if (a == conditionIwant) {
    // append to head: 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"> </ script>
};  //or something like this
```

How can I insert jquery.js only if a condition is true?

Comment: Do you have access to another technology - PHP, ASP, etc. This is really something you should do server side if possible.

Answer (score 14):

This is really simple:

```
if(somethingIsTrue) {
  var sc = document.createElement('script');
  sc.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js';
  sc.type = 'text/javascript';
  if(typeof sc['async'] !== 'undefined') {
     sc.async = true;
  }  
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sc);
}
```

Comment: eventually you can add `sc.async = true;` if you don't want to block parallel downloads.